# How do you combine multiple boxplots from a List of data-frames?

Tags: list, r, ggplot2, data-visualization, dataframe

This is a repost from the Statistics portion of the Stack Exchange.  I had asked the question there, I was advised to ask this question here.  So here it is.

I have a list of data-frames.  Each data-frame has a similar structure.  There is only one column in each data-frame that is numeric.  Because of my data-requirements it is essential that each data-frame has different lengths.  I want to create a boxplot of the numerical values, categorized over the attributes in another column.  But the boxplot should include information from all the data-frames.

I hope it is a clear question. I will post sample data soon.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sam,

I'm assuming this is a follow up to [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7259/combine-multiple-boxplots-in-a-lattice) question? Maybe your sample data will illustrate the nuances of your needs better (the "categorized over attributes in another column" part), but the same `melting` approach should work here.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
#Fake data
a <- data.frame(a = rnorm(10))
b <- data.frame(b = rnorm(100))
c <- data.frame(c = rnorm(1000))

#In a list
myList <- list(a,b,c)


#In a melting pot
df <- melt(myList)

#Separate boxplots for each data.frame
qplot(factor(variable), value, data = df, geom = "boxplot")
#All values plotted together as one boxplot
qplot(factor(1), value, data = df, geom = "boxplot")
```

Comment: Can't you just melt the list?

Comment: @hadley - indeed you can. I hadn't used `melt` specifically with lists before, so thanks for the tip. Will modify accordingly.

Comment: indeed yes, it is the followup to that question.  Thank you for the edit.

Comment: Note that you also need to add "library(reshape)" for this to work.

Comment: @DiomidisSpinellis - thanks, added that. Back in 2011 when this was answered, reshape was loaded by default when you loaded ggplot2...that's no longer the case so I updated the code.

Answer (score 1):

```
a<-data.frame(c(1,2),c("x","y"))
b<-data.frame(c(3,4,5),c("a","b","c"))
boxplot(c(a[1],b[1]))
```

With the "1"'s i select the column i want out of the data-frame.

A data-frames can not have different column-lengths (has to have same number of rows for each column), but you can tell boxplot to plot multiple datasets in parallel.

Comment: This solution will not work if it is to plot directly from a list.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `melt()` function and base R boxplot:

```
#Fake data
a <- data.frame(a = rnorm(10))
b <- data.frame(b = rnorm(100))
c <- data.frame(c = rnorm(100) + 5)

#In a list
myList <- list(a,b,c)

#In a melting pot
df <- melt(myList)

# plot using base R boxplot function
boxplot(value ~ variable, data = df)
```